# Make virtual box run with better rendering options (preformance should not be an issue)

Tags: virtualbox, drivers, adobe-photoshop, nvidia-graphics-card

I have virtual box running on my gaming laptop ASUS G75vw (Intel i7 3630QM, Nvidia GTX670M). I'm using Ubuntu now a days. But I need photoshop, thus I have windows 7 on my virtual box. Everything works fine but the text inside the photosop project is not rendered correctly at 66% or 33%. However it looks good at 100% and 50%. **Is there a way to allow the virtual box access to nvidia drivers or something along those lines?**
I have maxed the rescourse settings for my win 7 virtual pc. Oracle VM VirtualBox Guest Additions are installed on the guest OS, and so are the experimental 3d drivers thing. The video memory is set at 256 mb with 3d aceleration enabled.

The first image shows how it looks on 66% zoom in PS. The second image shows how it looks at 100%
[image: This is how it looks on 66%]

The second image shows how it looks at 100% [image: This is how it looks on 100%]

Comment: no it is not possible to make direct use of the nvidia drivers or hardware when running virtualbox. from its perspective, they are parts in a different computer.